# how to align text view in between two images

Tags: android

my text view not align on center  below is my code this is my scren shot

[image]

i just want to align text view center of screen  help me please

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/lytTitlebar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
      android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/imgNavBack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/nav_back"

        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        android:text="@string/category_list"


        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgNavBack"

        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/imgRefresh"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/refresh"

        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        android:text="@string/category_list"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgNavBack"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgRefresh"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
```

Comment: @user2589245 make sure you have check this for all screen resolution as well as `portrait` and `landscape`

Comment: instead of right/left, try using start/end for better support for portrait and landscape

Answer (score 1):

Just copy layout and replace with your icon it will work.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ff4444" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/header_toogel_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/header_search_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sub_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Your Text Will Be Here"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use both for textview

```
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

and

```
android:layout_centerHorizontical="true"
```

or

you can use

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```